# Show $P(A\setminus B)=P(A) - P(A\cap B)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

How do I show that for a probability measure $P$ it holds that for $A,B \in \Omega:$ $$P(A\setminus B)=P(A) - P(A\cap B)$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:

$$A=(A\cap B)\cup (A\setminus B)$$

and the union is disjoint.

Comment: Thank you very much!